# Scenario for crashing Galera cluster while deleting records

Tags: mysql, crash, mariadb, galera

We are testing Galera crash to reproduce one of the prod issue while deleting record. **Version is 10.1.32**
**Can someone please help us with scenarios for crashing Galera cluster while deleting records. When does it crash? Is it related to foreign key or 'wsrep_slave_threads'?**

Please provide any help.

```
**Below is the actual Prod log when the cluster failed -**
2018-08-16 16:24:27 140366938635008 [ERROR] Slave SQL: Error 'Unknown table 'DB_TOTAL4DEV_P.users_last_login_2'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'drop table `DB_TOTAL4DEV_P`.`users_last_login_2`', Internal MariaDB error code: 1051
2018-08-16 16:24:27 140366938635008 [Warning] WSREP: RBR event 1 Query apply warning: 1, 309050572
2018-08-16 16:24:27 140366938635008 [Warning] WSREP: Ignoring error for TO isolated action: source: 4533077b-9f57-11e8-94aa-6b070f22a4b5 version: 3 local: 0 state: APPLYING flags: 65 conn_id: 492382 trx_id: -1 seqnos (l: 805550, g: 309050572, s: 309050571, d: 309050571, ts: 223731321595519)
2018-08-16 16:24:28 140366938635008 [ERROR] Slave SQL: Error 'Unknown table 'DB_TOTAL4DEV_P.users_last_login_2'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'drop table `DB_TOTAL4DEV_P`.`users_last_login_2`', Internal MariaDB error code: 1051
2018-08-16 16:24:28 140366938635008 [Warning] WSREP: RBR event 1 Query apply warning: 1, 309050575
2018-08-16 16:24:28 140366938635008 [Warning] WSREP: Ignoring error for TO isolated action: source: 56daeaa4-9e8e-11e8-b891-6f203bac329a version: 3 local: 0 state: APPLYING flags: 65 conn_id: 708893 trx_id: -1 seqnos (l: 805553, g: 309050575, s: 309050574, d: 309050574, ts: 310032366214700)
2018-08-16 16:28:45 140366938635008 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find record in 'users_last_login'
2018-08-16 16:28:45 140366938635008 [ERROR] Slave SQL: Could not execute Delete_rows_v1 event on table DB_TOTAL4DEV_P.users_last_login; Can't find record in 'users_last_login', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log FIRST, end_log_pos 1862, Internal MariaDB error code: 1032
2018-08-16 16:28:45 140366938635008 [Warning] WSREP: RBR event 3 Delete_rows_v1 apply warning: 120, 309051933
2018-08-16 16:28:45 140366938635008 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to apply app buffer: seqno: 309051933, status: 1
2018-08-16 16:28:45 140366938635008 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to apply trx: source: 808e3422-9dcd-11e8-bbc0-3ab028afd1b7 version: 3 local: 0 state: APPLYING flags: 1 conn_id: 893106 trx_id: 15068161908 seqnos (l: 806931, g: 309051933, s: 309051932, d: 309051868, ts: 393116532516870)
2018-08-16 16:28:45 140366938635008 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to apply trx 309051933 4 times
2018-08-16 16:28:45 140366938635008 [ERROR] WSREP: Node consistency compromised, aborting...
```

Comment: we have so far tried to delete records having foreign key and also changing wsrep_slave_threads values to high value but no effect - the cluster did not crash.

Comment: Please show us the `DELETE` statement, the table's `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, and your wsrep settings.

Comment: @KamleshBhat how did you fix this?